# Gradle Dependencies - What does + mean

Tags: gradle

I see some dependencies similar to below -

```
compile("com.service:service-boot:0.3.+")
```

What does + mean? I have also seen "changing: true" in some places , what does this mean as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the `0.3.+` means the latest version to match `0.3.0 < n < 0.4.0`.  The check is performed and the result is cached for some period.  So this version could be `0.3.3` then when `0.3.4` is released sometime in the future gradle will detect this and update your local dependency.

The `changing = true` means gradle should check the md5 of the artifact every build to see if the value has changed and the dependency should be updated.  If the dependency has a version ending in `-SNAPSHOT` then this value is `true` by default.

Reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:dynamic_versions_and_changing_modules